# list index out of range: How can I deal with list index error

Tags: list, indexing

```
products = [
    {"id":1, "name": "Chocolate Sandwich Cookies", "department": "snacks", "aisle": "cookies cakes", "price": 3.50},
    {"id":2, "name": "All-Seasons Salt", "department": "pantry", "aisle": "spices seasonings", "price": 4.99},
    {"id":3, "name": "Robust Golden Unsweetened Oolong Tea", "department": "beverages", "aisle": "tea", "price": 2.49},
    {"id":4, "name": "Smart Ones Classic Favorites Mini Rigatoni With Vodka Cream Sauce", "department": "frozen", "aisle": "frozen meals", "price": 6.99},
    {"id":5, "name": "Green Chile Anytime Sauce", "department": "pantry", "aisle": "marinades meat preparation", "price": 7.99},
    {"id":6, "name": "Dry Nose Oil", "department": "personal care", "aisle": "cold flu allergy", "price": 21.99},
    {"id":7, "name": "Pure Coconut Water With Orange", "department": "beverages", "aisle": "juice nectars", "price": 3.50},
    {"id":8, "name": "Cut Russet Potatoes Steam N' Mash", "department": "frozen", "aisle": "frozen produce", "price": 4.25},
    {"id":9, "name": "Light Strawberry Blueberry Yogurt", "department": "dairy eggs", "aisle": "yogurt", "price": 6.50},
    {"id":10, "name": "Sparkling Orange Juice & Prickly Pear Beverage", "department": "beverages", "aisle": "water seltzer sparkling water", "price": 2.99},
    {"id":11, "name": "Peach Mango Juice", "department": "beverages", "aisle": "refrigerated", "price": 1.99},
    {"id":12, "name": "Chocolate Fudge Layer Cake", "department": "frozen", "aisle": "frozen dessert", "price": 18.50},
    {"id":13, "name": "Saline Nasal Mist", "department": "personal care", "aisle": "cold flu allergy", "price": 16.00},
    {"id":14, "name": "Fresh Scent Dishwasher Cleaner", "department": "household", "aisle": "dish detergents", "price": 4.99},
    {"id":15, "name": "Overnight Diapers Size 6", "department": "babies", "aisle": "diapers wipes", "price": 25.50},
    {"id":16, "name": "Mint Chocolate Flavored Syrup", "department": "snacks", "aisle": "ice cream toppings", "price": 4.50},
    {"id":17, "name": "Rendered Duck Fat", "department": "meat seafood", "aisle": "poultry counter", "price": 9.99},
    {"id":18, "name": "Pizza for One Suprema Frozen Pizza", "department": "frozen", "aisle": "frozen pizza", "price": 12.50},
    {"id":19, "name": "Gluten Free Quinoa Three Cheese & Mushroom Blend", "department": "dry goods pasta", "aisle": "grains rice dried goods", "price": 3.99},
    {"id":20, "name": "Pomegranate Cranberry & Aloe Vera Enrich Drink", "department": "beverages", "aisle": "juice nectars", "price": 4.25}
]
product_ids = []

while True:
    product_id = input ("Hey please input a product identifier: ")
    if product_id == "done":
        break
    else:
        product_ids.append(product_id)

def lookup_product_by_id(product_id):
    matching_products = [product for product in products if product["id"] == product_id]
    return matching_products[0]

raw_total = 0

for product_id in product_ids:
    product = lookup_product_by_id(product_id)
    raw_total += product["price"]
    print(str(product["id"]) + " " + product["name"] + " " + str(product["price"]))
```

It says ' list index out of range ' I don't know what is wrong with me. How can I solve this problem? I don't know how 'return matching_products[0]' and 'product = lookup_product_by_id(product_id)' are interracted.

Comment: You probably have an off by one error. Or do you know, that if you enter i.e. 5 as input, your lookup method will return you the list item with id 6?